# Generate 2 random integer list of different size

Tags: python-3.x, list, random

I am trying to generate 2 list with different size consisting with random numbers. I can generate 2 list with random numbers, but how to achieve 2 different length of lists?

```
import random
list1 = random.sample(xrange(100), 10)
list2 = random.sample(xrange(100), 10)
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Need to generate the lists with 2 random different sizes as well, as if both the lists are completely random.

Comment: Do you mean that the size of the lists has to be random too?

Comment: Yes. currently, the list size is 10 in both cases. If it can be randomize as well

Comment: You can change the size parameter to something like `random.randint(1, 100)` if you want the size to be for example between 1 and 100.

Comment: Just replace '10' by a call to the method [random.randint()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.randint), this should do the job...

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Hope this would help.

If you want to create random number list of two different sizes. Then you can explicitly, pass the size of the list as a second argument, as given below.

```
import random

list1 = random.sample(xrange(100), 100)
list2 = random.sample(xrange(100), 10)
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Ouput will be :

```
[46, 73, 13, 89, 44, 23, 74, 8, 19, 79, 36, 80, 85, 42, 82, 39, 61, 15, 27, 68, 67, 30, 11, 21, 86, 16, 63, 95, 17, 90, 37, 81, 20, 71, 93, 99, 40, 6, 47, 92, 58, 35, 12, 2, 10, 98, 87, 50, 51, 97, 70, 65, 78, 22, 72, 45, 59, 0, 52, 14, 1, 84, 43, 24, 54, 31, 18, 69, 7, 75, 53, 25, 57, 94, 83, 66, 3, 5, 88, 32, 4, 28, 29, 55, 9, 77, 60, 62, 41, 76, 48, 56, 34, 91, 33, 96, 49, 38, 26, 64]

[82, 58, 74, 61, 21, 77, 53, 35, 44, 59]
```

Now if you want to randomly decide the size of the list, the pass a random number as a second argument, by using randint function

```
import random

list1 = random.sample(range(100), random.randint(1,101))
list2 = random.sample(range(100), random.randint(1,101))
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Output would be:

```
[93, 60, 82, 53, 16, 42, 0, 68, 88, 11, 89, 62, 38, 14, 27, 8, 45, 25, 83, 97, 94]
[30, 5, 19, 11, 14, 6, 7, 86, 16, 53, 71, 12, 90, 32]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, which would randomly generate the size between 1 and 10.

```
import random
list1 = random.sample(range(100), random.randint(1,10))
list2 = random.sample(range(100), random.randint(1,10))
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

This will generate random length of the lists. Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

You need to randomize the second Parameter as well to become lists of random size:

```
import random

list1 = random.sample(range(100), random.randint(1,10))
list2 = random.sample(range(100), random.randint(1,10))
print(list1)
print(list2)
```